# How to copy a specific text from html attribute to a PHP String?

Tags: php

```
<input type="hidden" name="payFormParams" id="payFormParams" value="payment_type=PaymentForm&merchant_id=117589463&trnType=P&errorPage=%2Fscripts%2Fpayment%2Fpayment%2Easp&approvedPage=&declinedPage=&epe_client_found=false&trnLanguage=eng&shipping_method=&ref1=&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=&shippingMethod=&deliveryEstimate=&ordTax1Price=&ordTax2Price=&ordItemPrice=0&ordShippingPrice=0&trnOrderNumber=51029&trnAmount=5%2E00&ordName=Surreal+View&ordEmailAddress=xx%40gmail%2Ecom&ordPhoneNumber=2039581030&ordAddress1=3501+Jack+Northrop+Ave&ordCity=Hawthorne&ordProvince=CA&ordPostalCode=90250&ordCountry=US&paymentMethod=CC&trnCardOwner=Suyash&trnCardCvd=xxx&cavBirthMonth=&cavBirthDay=&cavBirthYear=&cavSin=&paymentAction=&trnCardNumber=xxxxxxxxx0412300&trnExpMonth=xx&trnExpYear=xx&aDFinancingType=&aDPlanNumber=&aDGracePeriod=&aDTerm=&hashValue=6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278">
```

This is the code which is generated, I made a string $payid, but it copies the whole code. All I need is hashValue=

```php
$payid = getStr($html, '< input type="hidden" name="payFormParams" id="payFormParams" value="','">');
```

But I want to just copy the value of `hashValue` into `$payid` that is just `6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278`
Can someone please help me how to do this? I am lost. I need help with it.

Comment: Will the hash value always be the last key/value post pair in your url string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use explode to get the value of the hash if it is the last key/value pair in the string using the following method...

***Online PHP Editer:***

https://3v4l.org/kUrJs

```php
$html = '<input type="hidden" name="payFormParams" id="payFormParams" value="payment_type=PaymentForm&merchant_id=117589463&trnType=P&errorPage=%2Fscripts%2Fpayment%2Fpayment%2Easp&approvedPage=&declinedPage=&epe_client_found=false&trnLanguage=eng&shipping_method=&ref1=&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=&shippingMethod=&deliveryEstimate=&ordTax1Price=&ordTax2Price=&ordItemPrice=0&ordShippingPrice=0&trnOrderNumber=51029&trnAmount=5%2E00&ordName=Surreal+View&ordEmailAddress=xx%40gmail%2Ecom&ordPhoneNumber=2039581030&ordAddress1=3501+Jack+Northrop+Ave&ordCity=Hawthorne&ordProvince=CA&ordPostalCode=90250&ordCountry=US&paymentMethod=CC&trnCardOwner=Suyash&trnCardCvd=xxx&cavBirthMonth=&cavBirthDay=&cavBirthYear=&cavSin=&paymentAction=&trnCardNumber=xxxxxxxxx0412300&trnExpMonth=xx&trnExpYear=xx&aDFinancingType=&aDPlanNumber=&aDGracePeriod=&aDTerm=&hashValue=6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278">';

//Explode the input tag as a string at the `=` operators.
$ex = explode('=', $html);

// now use the count of the exploded array as a reference and subtract the keys by one to get the value of the hash.
$target = $ex[count($ex) - 1];

// This leaves you with a value that has the hash followed by a double quote and the closing tag for the input, explode again using the double quote
$hash = explode('"', $target);

// This leaves the hash and the symbols in our array, use the first key of 0 to get the value of the hash as you want it.
$targetHash = $hash[0];
```

***RETURNS:***

`6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278`

If you are not sure where the hash is in the string, you could use the explode method and search for the key of `hash`, knowing the NEXT value will be the actual hash...So it would look something like the following...

Once you explode the string by `=`, you have the value `&hashValue` to search for, you know the next value in the exploded array will be the actual hash. So we run a foreach and look for that value and then locate the key of the `key` turned `value` and we use that to search for the hash, ie `key + 1`. This will give us the hash with double quotes explode those and get the hash.

```php
$html = '<input type="hidden" name="payFormParams" id="payFormParams" value="payment_type=PaymentForm&merchant_id=117589463&trnType=P&errorPage=%2Fscripts%2Fpayment%2Fpayment%2Easp&approvedPage=&declinedPage=&epe_client_found=false&trnLanguage=eng&shipping_method=&ref1=&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=&shippingMethod=&deliveryEstimate=&ordTax1Price=&ordTax2Price=&ordItemPrice=0&ordShippingPrice=0&trnOrderNumber=51029&trnAmount=5%2E00&ordName=Surreal+View&ordEmailAddress=xx%40gmail%2Ecom&ordPhoneNumber=2039581030&ordAddress1=3501+Jack+Northrop+Ave&ordCity=Hawthorne&ordProvince=CA&ordPostalCode=90250&ordCountry=US&paymentMethod=CC&trnCardOwner=Suyash&trnCardCvd=xxx&cavBirthMonth=&cavBirthDay=&cavBirthYear=&cavSin=&paymentAction=&hashValue=6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278=&trnCardNumber=xxxxxxxxx0412300&trnExpMonth=xx&trnExpYear=xx&aDFinancingType=&aDPlanNumber=&aDGracePeriod=&aDTerm=>';

//--> Explode at the `=` operator and create an array to hold the exploded values
$ex = explode('=', $html);

//--> Run a loop and iterate over the key/value pairs to search for our target
foreach($ex as $key => $value){
  //--> Since we exploded at the `=` operator, we know the target string is `&hashValue` iterate through array and find that key/value pair
  if($value === '&hashValue'){

    //--> We know the hash is the next value in the array, so use the current key + 1 to find the hash
    $targetKey = $key + 1;
    //--> The next step is not needed if you do not have double quotes after or before the hash.
    //--> Simply use the targetKey to get the value of the hash --> $ex[$targetKey]
    //--> The following only applies if there is a trailing double quote left on the hash
    //--> If you have 6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278" left over
    $hash = explode('"', $ex[$targetKey]);
    $targetHash = $hash[0];
    echo $targetHash;
  }
}
```

***RETURNS:***

`6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278`

Now you can copy the value of the hash in $targetHash anywhere you'd like...

If you would like a better understanding of how this works, simply add a print_r() after each step and see how the explode returns the information with each step...

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<input type="hidden" name="payFormParams" id="payFormParams" value="payment_type=PaymentForm&merchant_id=117589463&trnType=P&errorPage=%2Fscripts%2Fpayment%2Fpayment%2Easp&approvedPage=&declinedPage=&epe_client_found=false&trnLanguage=eng&shipping_method=&ref1=&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=&shippingMethod=&deliveryEstimate=&ordTax1Price=&ordTax2Price=&ordItemPrice=0&ordShippingPrice=0&trnOrderNumber=51029&trnAmount=5%2E00&ordName=Surreal+View&ordEmailAddress=xx%40gmail%2Ecom&ordPhoneNumber=2039581030&ordAddress1=3501+Jack+Northrop+Ave&ordCity=Hawthorne&ordProvince=CA&ordPostalCode=90250&ordCountry=US&paymentMethod=CC&trnCardOwner=Suyash&trnCardCvd=xxx&cavBirthMonth=&cavBirthDay=&cavBirthYear=&cavSin=&paymentAction=&trnCardNumber=xxxxxxxxx0412300&trnExpMonth=xx&trnExpYear=xx&aDFinancingType=&aDPlanNumber=&aDGracePeriod=&aDTerm=&hashValue=6a1562f5c4901522ab6926a4caf9f278">';

     $preg='/<input .*?hashValue=(.*?)".*?>/'; //Regular expression
     preg_match_all($preg,$str,$array);  //Match regular expression
     echo $array[1][0]; //return string
```

Comment: adding a description around your answer will help the person who asked the question understand why your answer helps.